# How add Aramex Shipping to opencart

Tags: opencart, opencart-3, opencart-module, aramex

I have a Website in opencart and also have an account on Aramex but I just want to integrate Aramex shipping to my opencart store.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to purchase  proper plugin for this if you research little bit about this
https://store.webkul.com/Opencart-Marketplace-aramex-Shipping.html
here is the link